# Vue-Multiselect and Vuex: Having a value from store pre-selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-multiselect

imagine a Vuejs-Application with Vuex. I want to have a mulitselect-dropdown. Basic example in the Vue-component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <multiselect
      v-model="values"
      :options="options">
    </multiselect>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
  export default {
    components: { Multiselect },
    data () {
      return {
        values: null,
        options: ['bar', 'foo', 'hello','test']
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
```

Now, if I initialize "values" in data like this:

```
values: ["test"]
```

The multiselect-dropdown has "test" as already selected option. I can also deselect it on click and select it again, since it is in options.

If I try to initialize my values like this:

```
values:[this.$store.state.variableIwantPreselected]
```

it does not fully work. In the selection-area/dropdown search field, those green boxes with the selected item's name are normally displayed. For me, it does not display the **string** in the green box, **which is in this.$store.state.variableIwantPreselected**, but o*nly a small green box with nothing written in it*.

I think I missed something about Vuex and lifecycle hooks, but I could not figure out what.

Comment: are you sure that this.$store.state.variableIwantPreselected contains a string of values array? did you try with a console.log(this.$store.state.variableIwantPreselected) to test it?

Comment: I just did. The value is a string, and it is in the store. however, if I make the variableIwantPreselected as an array containing one string, it is shown in the green vue-multiselect box as ["variableIwantPreselected"]. Do I need to have an object, instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you working with Vuex the best way to manipulate data in storage use state,
  mutations,  actions and getters to get any type of data. For more information check [this post](https://medium.com/fullstackio/managing-state-in-vue-js-23a0352b1c87)

Comment: I don't want to manipulate the store. I want to get one value from it to initialize multiselect with a preselected value in its values. The value comes from the storage, but is not changed. So, I would need a getter for the value, but I cannot use the value itself?

Comment: Yeah. You need a getter in your storage. In certain cases access  directly working, it seems in this case (with arrays) not working

Answer (score 1):

A further note for people running into similar problems: check, when your component is rendered/loaded. In my case, it was loaded before the value in the store was changed (tends to happen when you use vue-router and have several components displaying with only one route).

Solution: take a deeper look into the updated lifecycle hook.

I now call a function in the updated lifecycle hook. The function is declared in methods. The function checks, if my values (now initialized as empty list) has a length of 0. If so, the store value is pushed to the list.

in data:

```
values: []
```

in methods:

```
checkValues (){
    if(this.values.length === 0){
        this.values.push(this.$store.state.variableIwantPreselected)
    }
}
```

in updated():

```
this.checkValues()
```